# Jest with Babel ^7.0.0-rc.1 issue

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I'm getting the below error when trying to run Jest test using babel 7

import React from 'react';
    ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

My config is as follows -

**jest.config.json**

```
{
   "rootDir": "../../",
   "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
  "/node_modules/",
  "/test/e2e"
],
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
  "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
},
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest"
 }
}
```

**.babelrc** (Next 6 comes with @babel/env & @babel/react I think!)

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^23.4.0",
    "puppeteer": "^1.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.1"
}
```

I've tried quite a few configuration settings but nothing seems to be working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since babel has stopped publishing stage 2 presets. There are some beta verison available to babel core and presets. tou can exclude dynamic import if you're not doing code splitting. Try these version and update your devDependencies and let me know if the issue still persists:

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.54",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.0.0-beta.54",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.0.0-beta.54",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "7.0.0-beta.54",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "7.0.0-beta.54",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "7.0.0-beta.54",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "7.0.0-beta.54",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "7.0.0-beta.54",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.0.0-beta.54",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "7.0.0-beta.54",
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
"babel-jest": "^23.0.1",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
}
```

.bablerc

```
{
"presets": [
 "@babel/preset-env",
 "@babel/preset-react"
],
"plugins": [
 "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
 "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
[
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
  {
    "legacy": true
  }
],
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions"
 ]
}
```